# Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException Yii2

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, yii2-advanced-app

I am a beginner in Yii2.I am studying Yii2 from this [Yii2 documentation link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html).When I run this file,its giving me the following error.[image]

I have created a CountryController within C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\frontend\controllers\CountryController.php.

EDIT:

After modifying the namespace in controller,Now am getting issue in View.[image]

Comment: What namespace did you use in your CountryController class?

Comment: @MrGoobri I have used `namespace app\controllers;'

Comment: try `namescape frontend\controllers;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is basically saying that it cannot find your Controller. So what you need to do is ensure that your file is stored in the same place as your namespace implies. My suspicion is that they don't align. So...

You are using the namespace of `app\controllers` but you store your file in `yii\frontend\controllers`. I suspect `yii\frontend\controllers` does not correspond to `app\controllers`. I suspect, all you'll have to do is use the namespace `frontend\controllers` - but it depends on what aliases you are using.

Comment: I have modified the namespace,but now am getting a new error in the view.I have attached the screenshot

Comment: This is different problem. I suggest you open a new question because other people may be searching for solutions to your second problem, which they'll not be able to find hidden within your first problem - if you follow. :) I will answer your second question too.